# Verify a password is hashed

Tags: php, passwords

To make it really simple, let's say I've got an application with passwords stored somewhere (it doesn't matter where).

The php runs:
⋅ `$hash = password_hash($user_input, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` when the user modifies the password, and then stores `$hash`,
⋅ `$Access = password_verify($user_input, $hash)` when the user tries to log-in.

I would like to be sure and check if the stored password is actually hashed.
In some unusual cases, it can happen that the password is chosen and written manually by someone. So I'd like the php to be able to know when the password is not hashed, and hash it to store it back in a secure form.
Something like:

```
if (!is_hashed($hash)) {
    // Hash the password
    password_hash($hash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
}
```

Is there an easy way to check if a string is the hash of the password or a regular string ?

Comment: No, not really. You could check if something would be a "weak password" and if it is, then it is likely that it is not a hash. But you can't tell a hash from a non-hash, both are just some characters.

Comment: Also, it might be that the hashes all have a specific length. If something doesn't match that length, then it isn't a hash. That would be another easy thing to test against. Depends on your setup, though.

Comment: How is someone able to write the password manually? Surely you can hash it at this point before running the insert query?

Comment: If a user wants a password like: `$2y$10$20MYIQOG7dSkI5najBISXOQvEm5rMFCUan80b4VK2tCliGEW9FfIi` let them, you shouldn't be checking whether its already a hash, your system should be hashing regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`password_get_info()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-get-info.php) to get informations about hashed passwords. It will always return an array like this:

```
[
    'algo' => int,
    'algoName' => 'name of algorithm|unknown',
    'options' => [/*options for algo, or empty if unknown */]
]
```

In case your hash was not really hashed, the function will return the `unknown` case array, which looks like this:

```
[
    'algo' => 0,
    'algoName' => 'unknown',
    'options' => []
]
```

You can check if the algorithm is unknown and hash it then:

```
$hashInfo = password_get_info($hash);

if ($hashInfo['algoName'] === 'unknown') {
    $hash = password_hash($hash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    //Save new hash to DB
}
```

Comment: In case the password is hashed, but `password_get_info()` returns `unknown` as algorithm name, `password_verify()` cannot analyse the hash as well. So in that case the password is broken anyway and the user needs to update his password manually.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @PhilippMaurer. I am looking at the function `password_needs_rehash()` right now, related to `password_get_info()`. I'll try to do something with that.

Comment: @TakitIsy The problem with `password_needs_rehash()` is, that it might tell you, that a password was hashed, but is not secure anymore. Hashing it again afterwards, because you think it is an unhashed password, will create an invalid password, that was hashed twice. Because your database has the state, that a password might not be hashed at all, you need to be able to differ those two states, which you can with `password_get_info()`. Adding both functions might be the best solution though. Working with `password_needs_rehash()` only might create issues in the future.

Comment: I think I'm gonna use `password_needs_rehash()` only when the user has logged in, and when I'm sure the hash is really a hash. That way, I'll only refresh the hash if it's necessary (like options changed or hashing evolved with php version…)

Comment: @TakitIsy Just keep in mind, that you want to rehash the password the user provided by a successful login, not the old hash :-) In case the hash is not a hash you might either implement the `php_get_info()` check or a password check that works without `password_verify()` to make sure that you get to the point when the user is logged in.  Good luck and no bugs.

Comment: Thank you -- this is useful for running tests to ensure a string has indeed been hashed

Answer (score 0):

password_hash returns the hashed password if it succeeds or false if it fails.

```
if(!password_hash($password)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: What if  `$password` is already hashed ? It's gonna be successfully hashed again, no ?

Comment: If i'm understanding correctly, this breaks the security model.  If password doesn't equal an expected hash then change it so it does.  So everyone can log in :-)

Comment: Maybe no, we don't know what `do stuff` is doing!… :)

Comment: if it is already hashed it will hash again if you want that but why would you want to hash it twice?

Comment: I need it to be hashed and stored only if it's not already a hashed password.

Comment: There is not really a function for that but you can try checking the length and the beginning of the hash. The beginning of the hash looks like $2y$12$ and has a length of 60. The only thing I can think of for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> The php runs:
>
> - `password_hash($user_input);` when the user modifies the password and stores it,
> - `$Access = password_verify($user_input, $hash)` when the user tries to log-in.

At this point, passwords that aren't saved as hashes, but as unhashed passwords, would fail the verification, as access is only granted if the *hashed* input matches the saved data, which should be / has to be a hash.

As for identifying if something is a has or not, as I commented, both are just some character string. You can't tell a hash apart from some random passwords. But hashes have a very specific length, so you could find non-hashed passwords that way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments, I am thinking about it.